# Trampoline based linked list (lisp tree) to string with cycles

Tags: javascript, recursion, continuations, trampolines

I have problem with my trampoline based function that stringify lisp list. Here is the code:

```js
function Pair(car, cdr) {
  this.car = car;
  this.cdr = cdr;
}
const nil = new function Nil() {};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Pair.fromArray = function(array) {
    var result = nil;
    var i = array.length;
    while (i--) {
        let car = array[i];
        if (car instanceof Array) {
            car = Pair.fromArray(car);
        }
        result = new Pair(car, result);
    }
    return result;
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
function Thunk(fn, cont = () => {}) {
    this.fn = fn;
    this.cont = cont;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Thunk.prototype.toString = function() {
    return '#<Thunk>';
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
function trampoline(fn) {
    return function(...args) {
        return unwind(fn.apply(this, args));
    };
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
function unwind(result) {
    while (result instanceof Thunk) {
        const thunk = result;
        result = result.fn();
        if (!(result instanceof Thunk)) {
            thunk.cont();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// original function have different data types here
// with simplified version this is fine
function toString(x) {
  return x.toString();
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
const pair_to_string = (function() {
    const prefix = (pair, rest) => {
        var result = [];
        if (pair.ref) {
            result.push(pair.ref + '(');
        } else if (!rest) {
            result.push('(');
        }
        return result;
    };
    const postfix = (pair, rest) => {
        if (!rest || pair.ref) {
            return [')'];
        }
        return [];
    };
    return trampoline(function pairToString(pair, quote, extra = {}) {
        const {
            nested,
            result = [],
            cont = () => {
                result.push(...postfix(pair, nested));
            }
        } = extra;
        result.push(...prefix(pair, nested));
        let car;
        if (pair.cycles && pair.cycles.car) {
            car = pair.cycles.car;
        } else {
            car = toString(pair.car, quote, true, { nested: false, result, cont });
        }
        if (car !== undefined) {
            result.push(car);
        }
        return new Thunk(() => {
            if (pair.cdr instanceof Pair) {
                if (pair.cycles && pair.cycles.cdr) {
                    result.push(' . ');
                    result.push(pair.cycles.cdr);
                } else {
                    if (pair.cdr.ref) {
                        result.push(' . ');
                    } else {
                        result.push(' ');
                    }
                    return pairToString(pair.cdr, quote, {
                        nested: true,
                        result,
                        cont
                    });
                }
            } else if (pair.cdr !== nil) {
                result.push(' . ');
                result.push(toString(pair.cdr, quote));
            }
        }, cont);
    });
})();

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Pair.prototype.toString = function(quote) {
    var result = [];
    pair_to_string(this, quote, {result});
    return result.join('');
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
function range(n) {
    return new Array(n).fill(0).map((_, i) => i);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function markCycles(pair) {
    var seen_pairs = [];
    var cycles = [];
    var refs = [];
    function visit(pair) {
        if (!seen_pairs.includes(pair)) {
            seen_pairs.push(pair);
        }
    }
    function set(node, type, child, parents) {
        if (child instanceof Pair) {
            if (parents.includes(child)) {
                if (!refs.includes(child)) {
                    refs.push(child);
                }
                if (!node.cycles) {
                    node.cycles = {};
                }
                node.cycles[type] = child;
                if (!cycles.includes(node)) {
                    cycles.push(node);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    const detect = trampoline(function detect_thunk(pair, parents) {
        if (pair instanceof Pair) {
            delete pair.ref;
            delete pair.cycles;
            visit(pair);
            parents.push(pair);
            var car = set(pair, 'car', pair.car, parents);
            var cdr = set(pair, 'cdr', pair.cdr, parents);
            var thunks = [];
            if (!car) {
                detect(pair.car, parents.slice());
            }
            if (!cdr) {
                const cdr_args = [pair.cdr, parents.slice()];
                return new Thunk(() => {
                    return detect_thunk(...cdr_args);
                });
            }
        }
    });
    function mark_node(node, type) {
        if (node.cycles[type] instanceof Pair) {
            const count = ref_nodes.indexOf(node.cycles[type]);
            node.cycles[type] = `#${count}#`;
        }
    }
    detect(pair, []);
    var ref_nodes = seen_pairs.filter(node => refs.includes(node));
    ref_nodes.forEach((node, i) => {
        node.ref = `#${i}=`;
    });
    cycles.forEach(node => {
        mark_node(node, 'car');
        mark_node(node, 'cdr');
    });
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// this works fine
//console.log(Pair.fromArray([[[range(8000), range(10)]]]).toString());
var data = new Pair(1, new Pair(new Pair(2, nil), new Pair(3, nil)));
data.cdr.car.cdr = data.cdr;
data.cdr.cdr.cdr = data;
markCycles(data)
console.log(data.toString());
console.log("#0=(1 . #1=((2 . #1#) 3 . #0#)) - valid");
```

The problem is the last parenthesis is missing, I'm not sure how I should use continuation in trampoline to fix the issue.

Here is the code that was working without trampoline:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Pair.prototype.toString = function(quote, rest) {
    var arr = [];
    if (this.ref) {
        arr.push(this.ref + '(');
    } else if (!rest) {
        arr.push('(');
    }
    var value;
    if (this.cycles && this.cycles.car) {
        value = this.cycles.car;
    } else {
        value = toString(this.car, quote, true);
    }
    if (value !== undefined) {
        arr.push(value);
    }
    if (this.cdr instanceof Pair) {
        if (this.cycles && this.cycles.cdr) {
            arr.push(' . ');
            arr.push(this.cycles.cdr);
        } else {
            if (this.cdr.ref) {
                arr.push(' . ');
            } else {
                arr.push(' ');
            }
            const cdr = this.cdr.toString(quote, true);
            arr.push(cdr);
        }
    } else if (this.cdr !== nil) {
        arr = arr.concat([' . ', toString(this.cdr, quote, true)]);
    }
    if (!rest || this.ref) {
        arr.push(')');
    }
    return arr.join('');
};
```

I have two cases that should work first big list (8000 elements) and small cycle. With the code in stack snippet it work with long list but not with cycles without the trampoline it overflow the stack on big list. Also it's lisp so it need to work any any tree not only linked list.

**EDIT**: if you try to answer please at least don't change the data structures. It need to be Pair class with car and cdr and cycles need to be calculated before they are converted to string. So it work with multiple functions that check if data in memory is cycle.

Comment: I updated my answer. My updated answer no longer changes the `Pair` data structure. It also calculates the cycles in the `duplicates` method before converting the data structure to a string. I think that my updated answer solves all your problems. So, do check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do.

```js
const pure = value => ({ constructor: pure, value });

const bind = (monad, arrow) => ({ constructor: bind, monad, arrow });

const thunk = eval => ({ constructor: thunk, eval });

function evaluate(expression) {
    let expr = expression;
    let stack = null;

    while (true) {
        switch (expr.constructor) {
            case pure:
                if (stack === null) return expr.value;
                expr = stack.arrow(expr.value);
                stack = stack.stack;
                break;
            case bind:
                stack = { arrow: expr.arrow, stack };
                expr = expr.monad;
                break;
            case thunk:
                expr = expr.eval();
        }
    }
}

const monadic = func => thunk(() => {
    const gen = func();

    function next(data) {
        const { value, done } = gen.next(data);
        return done ? value : bind(value, next);
    }

    return next(undefined);
});

class Pair {
    constructor(car, cdr) {
        this.car = car;
        this.cdr = cdr;
    }

    static fromArray(array) {
        const loop = (array, index) => monadic(function* () {
            if (index === array.length) return pure(null);
            const item = array[index];
            const car = Array.isArray(item) ? yield loop(item, 0) : item;
            const cdr = yield loop(array, index + 1);
            return pure(new Pair(car, cdr));
        });

        return evaluate(loop(array, 0));
    }

    duplicates() {
        const visited = new WeakSet();
        const result = new WeakSet();

        const loop = pair => monadic(function* () {
            if (visited.has(pair)) {
                result.add(pair);
            } else {
                visited.add(pair);
                const { car, cdr } = pair;
                if (car instanceof Pair) yield loop(car);
                if (cdr instanceof Pair) yield loop(cdr);
            }

            return pure(result);
        });

        return evaluate(loop(this));
    }

    toString() {
        let result = "";

        const duplicates = this.duplicates();
        const visited = [];

        const loop = (pair, end) => monadic(function* () {
            const index = visited.indexOf(pair);

            if (index < 0) {
                const duplicate = duplicates.has(pair);

                if (duplicate) {
                    const last = visited.push(pair) - 1;
                    result += end ? ` . #${last}=(` : `#${last}=(`;
                } else result += end ? " " : "(";

                const { car, cdr } = pair;

                if (car instanceof Pair) yield loop(car, false);
                else result += JSON.stringify(car);

                if (cdr instanceof Pair) yield loop(cdr, true);
                else if (cdr === null) result += ")";
                else result += ` . ${JSON.stringify(cdr)})`;

                if (duplicate && end) result += ")";
            } else {
                result += end ? ` . #${index}#)` : `#${index}#`;
            }

            return pure(result);
        });

        return evaluate(loop(this, false));
    }
}

const data = new Pair(1, new Pair(new Pair(2, null), new Pair(3, null)));
data.cdr.car.cdr = data.cdr;
data.cdr.cdr.cdr = data;

console.log(data.toString());

const range = length => Array.from({ length }, (x, i) => i);

console.log(Pair.fromArray([[[range(8000), range(10)]]]).toString());
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, will try to use your code even that it's completely different then my original code. I know that you can write completely different code than the one in answer. but it doesn't mean that you should, simple and as closed to original code is best possible. Also It will be problematic in the way you have structured your code because I can't run duplicate function in every function that process the nodes I need that data to be stored in data structure itself.

Comment: @jcubic: You've been around plenty long enough to know that "simple and as [close] to original code is best possible" is not now it works around here.  Some may try that.  Others might suggest, "this radically different approach is a major improvement."  Either is legitimate, and the choice is up to the one answering.  I've come back to your recent questions several times and was chased off by the wall of code.  Perhaps it's a true MCVE, but I'd be surprised, and I haven't been willing to invest the effort.  Aadit was, and seems to have, at the very least, come up with a working solution.

Comment: I edited my question, please don't change the data structure. I can't use lazy evaluation, I've commented on your previous answer. This code is for lisp interpreter that need to manipulate of list structures.

Comment: @ScottSauyet this is second answer to my question with lazy evaluation that I can't use. I've commented on his first answer with similar code that I can't use lazy evaluation data structure, I need normal binary tree for my lisp.

Comment: @jcubic: That's up to you, of course.  As I read Aadit's code, it looks as though it's designed in such a way that no user of the data structure would ever have to know that it's lazy.  I acknowledge that his answer doesn't seem to be what you want.  If I find time (unlikely), I will see if I can try something that seems better to you.  But my first look gets me wanting to rewrite things, so... we'll see.  (For instance,  `Pair.fromArray = (array) => [... array] .reverse () .reduce ((a, b) => new Pair (Array .isArray (b) ? Pair.fromArray (b) : b, a), nil)` seems simpler.)

Comment: @jcubic Edited my answer to use classes instead of regular functions.

Comment: @jcubic `whnf` is a function which converts thunks into [lazy getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Smart_self-overwriting_lazy_getters). For example, `cons(1, 2)` will give you `{ car: 1, cdr: 2 }`. However, `cons(1, () => 2)` will also give you `{ car: 1, cdr: 2 }` but the `cdr` will not be computed until it is required. Hence, it's lazy. Laziness is important because it simplifies a lot of code. For example, look at the `Pair.fromArray` code. It uses recursion, is easy to understand, and it doesn't blow up the stack.

Comment: I know what `whnf` do. It's the same as your other answer that is also of no use to me, I've edited my question I don't want to change the data structure.

Comment: @jcubic I did not change the data structure. As you can see, the data structure is still a `Pair` with a `car` and a `cdr`.

Comment: You changed the data structure because it's now read only. `const data = Pair.fromArray([1,2,3,4]); data.cdr.cdr = data; console.log(data.toString());` you can't modify the list.

Comment: @jcubic Hmm... all right. Although, you can use `fix` solve that.

Comment: @jcubic Okay, I updated my answer. It doesn't use `whnf` anymore. I also simplified the logic of the `duplicates` and `toString` methods.

Comment: @jcubic I simplified the code even further, using generators to hide the monadic plumbing.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you have made to fix my problem, I think that you will be given the bounty automagically. The problem is that it's way too many abstractions, so I think that I would not be able to use your code. I will need to figure out on my own how to fix my problem, since no one except you give a chance. The reason why I can use your solution mainly because different constructs and concept your using, the project which I need this is for is called LIPS which suppose to stands for LIPS Is Pretty Simple. If I add this it will not longer be simple, I've already make it complex.

Comment: @jcubic So, if you don't manually award the bounty or accept my answer then the bounty will not be automatically awarded. Otherwise, if my answer gets at least 2 up votes then it will be automatically awarded but only half the bounty will be awarded. Source: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310204/783743

Comment: By the way, the only abstractions that I used were free monads, i.e. `data Free a where Pure :: a -> Free a; Bind :: Free a -> (a -> Free b) -> Free b`, and generator functions which are used to make the monadic code easier to read.

Comment: Ok, will try to use your code in my project, and see how it behave, I've awarded you the bounty will accept the answer and up vote after I've test the code.

Comment: After a year I've tried to revisit your code but when doing `console.log(Pair.fromArray([[[range(8000), range(10)]]]));` in stack snipped it consumed 100% of CPU and give stack overflow error in the same time. I need to kill the tab. So I think that I will not be able to use this code.

Comment: @jcubic It definitely shouldn't throw a stack overflow error. My `evaluate` function is stack safe. As you can see, it uses a while loop. In fact, I used my code to generate a pair from an array of 1,000,000 elements. It only took a few seconds and it didn't throw any stack overflow error. Not sure what the problem is on your end. What browser are you using? What are the specifications of your computer? Could you try running my code in a different environment? For example, could you try running my code in Node.js? If you can provide me more information then I'll be able to assist you better.

Comment: The problem is console.log that does things you don't expect. It prints null as cdr in console and gives stack overflow. Just try removing `.toString()` and run your snippet. I know that you use a similar technique as my simple trampoline, but I'm not exactly sure how it works and it gives errors. My first test is usually to run the code. I wanted to see if it logs the structure. Maybe the problem is that console.log prints this big data structure and it overflows. Will check Node.js that don't print whole data and see.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that in Node.js it works fine. I think that console.log in the browser has the same issue as my code. it probably also use recursion to print this data. Thank you very much for your help.